# multiprocessing and garbage collection

Tags: python, unix, garbage-collection, multiprocessing

In py2.6+, the `multiprocessing` module offers a `Pool` class, so one can do:

```
class Volatile(object):
    def do_stuff(self, ...):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        return pool.imap(...)
```

However, with the standard Python implementation at 2.7.2, this approach soon leads to "IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files". Apparently the `pool` object never gets garbage collected, so its processes never terminate, accumulating whatever descriptors are opened internally. I think this because the following works:

```
class Volatile(object):
    def do_stuff(self, ...):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        result = pool.map(...)
        pool.terminate()
        return result
```

I would like to keep the "lazy" iterator approach of `imap`; how does the garbage collector work in that case? How to fix the code?

Comment: can you give is a hint about what the `...` is inside your `pool.map(...)`?

Comment: Sure. `...` are read-only but CPU-heavy operations on member variables of the `Volatile` object. I'd like these to be executed in parallel, to improve performance. The object is not mutated for the duration of `do_stuff`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end, I ended up passing the `pool` reference around and terminating it manually once the `pool.imap` iterator was finished:

```
class Volatile(object):
    def do_stuff(self, ...):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        return pool, pool.imap(...)

    def call_stuff(self):
        pool, results = self.do_stuff()
        for result in results:
            # lazy evaluation of the imap
        pool.terminate()
```

---

In case anyone stumbles upon this solution in the future: the chunksize parameter is *very* important in `Pool.imap` (as opposed to plain `Pool.map`, where it didn't matter). I manually set it so that each process receives `1 + len(input) / len(pool)` jobs. Leaving it to the default `chunksize=1` gave me the same performance as if I didn't use parallel processing at all... bad.

I guess there's no real benefit to using ordered `imap` vs. ordered `map`, I just personally like  iterators better.

Comment: No, I mean I like iterators. Each generator is an iterator, btw.

Comment: In my case, I have to call `pool.terminate()` to get `gc.collect()` after that working. Otherwise, python just won't gc those objects referenced in pool, even with explicit `del pool`.

Answer (score 5):

In python, you basically have no guarantee of when things will be destroyed, and in this case this is not how multiprocessing pools are designed to be used.

The right thing to do is to share a single pool across multiple calls to the function. The easiest way to do that is to store the pool as a class (or, maybe, instance) variable:

```
class Dispatcher:
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    def do_stuff(self, ...):
        result = self.pool.map(...)
        return result
```

Comment: Doesn't `Pool()` fork internally? How would your solution "update" the state of the spawned processes to when `do_stuff()` is actually called? (as opposed to when `Dispatcher` is evaluated) Sounds rather complicated to keep everything in sync by hand with the master process.

Comment: Storing a pool as a member variable is fine; I don't understand your problem with state -- what state do you want to share? If you want your processes to share the same interpreter state, then you should probably use threads instead...

Comment: Thanks @Autopulated. Threads don't do much, due to GIL. State I want to share is the object that `do_stuff` was called on (=expensive operation on a massive read-only object, cannot afford copying).

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, even when all user references to the `pool` object are deleted, and no tasks are in the queue code, and all garbage collection is done, then still the **processes stay as unusable zombies** in the operating system - **plus we have 3 zombie service threads** from `Pool` hanging (Python 2.7 and 3.4):

```
>>> del pool
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> gc.garbage
[]
>>> threading.enumerate()
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 5632)>, <Thread(Thread-8, started daemon 5252)>, 
 <Thread(Thread-9, started daemon 5260)>, <Thread(Thread-7, started daemon 7608)>]
```

And further `Pool()`'s will add more and more process and thread zombies...  which stay until the main process is terminated.

It requires a special poke to stop such zombie pool - via its service thread `_handle_workers`:

```
>>> ths = threading.enumerate()
>>> for th in ths: 
...     try: th.name, th._state, th._Thread__target
...     except AttributeError: pass
...     
('MainThread', 1, None)
('Thread-8', 0, <function _handle_tasks at 0x01462A30>)
('Thread-9', 0, <function _handle_results at 0x014629F0>)
('Thread-7', 0, <function _handle_workers at 0x01462A70>)
>>> ths[-1]._state = multiprocessing.pool.CLOSE  # or TERMINATE
>>> threading.enumerate()
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 5632)>]
>>>
```

That terminates the other service threads and also terminates the child processes.

---

I think one problem is, that there is a **resource leak bug** in the Python library, which could be fixed by right usage of **`weakref`**'s.

The other point is that **`Pool` creation & termination is expensive** (including 3 service threads per pool just for management!), and there is ususually no reason to have much more worker processes than CPU cores (high CPU loads) or more than a limited number according to another limiting resource (e.g. network bandwidth). So its reasonable to treat a pool **more like a singular app global resource** (optionally managed by a timeout) rather than a quicky object just held by a closure (or a terminate()-workaround because of the bug).

For example:

```
try:
    _unused = pool   # reload safe global var
except NameError:
    pool = None

def get_pool():
    global pool
    if pool is None:
        atexit.register(stop_pool)
        pool = Pool(CPUCORES)
    return pool

def stop_pool():
    global pool
    if pool:
        pool.terminate()
        pool = None
```