# Python too many open files, eventlet and multiprocessing.dummy

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, eventlet

I have a Python 2.7 script running on Linux that crashes with `IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`.  When I run `lsof -p <script_pid>` to see what files the script has open, I see an increasing number of `anon_inode` files.

This script first downloads files from S3 using [`eventlet`](http://eventlet.net/) for concurrency.  It then processes the downloaded files using [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) for multithreading.  I have run the multithreaded code in isolation and found that it only leaks file descriptors when I include the following monkey patching for eventlet:

```
patcher.monkey_patch(thread=False)
```

Any ideas on how I could resolve this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I registered your issue here https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/197
would you share your isolation code for tests?
And do you experience any problems with just `monkey_patch()` ?

Comment: Thanks, @temoto!  Just monkey_patch() caused serious problems with multithreading.  I just discovered that I could selectively patch with import_patched -- do you know if eventlet.import_patched('boto.s3.connection') is sufficient?  I guess I don't fully understand what needs to be patched. If that's not an appropriate fix, I'll post isolation code.

Comment: Selective patch generally works well. Except for when target module does import in function some time later -- it will import non-patched version then. Please, post your code anyway.

Comment: Maybe it is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959598/multiprocessing-and-garbage-collection.

Answer (score 1):

I also run into this issue, on Ubuntu at least the open files limit for normal users defaults to 4096. So, if you are going to have more than ~4000 simultaneous connections you need to bump this up.

**Solution**: ***Raise open file descriptor limits***

Here's how to do it on ubuntu

add a line to end of **/etc/security/limits.conf** like

```
* soft nofile 16384    
* hard nofile 16384
```

The first column describes WHO the limit is to apply for. * is a wildcard, meaning all users. To raise the limits for root, you have to explicitly enter 'root' instead of '*'.

You also need to edit **/etc/pam.d/common-session*** and add the following line to the end:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

logout and then back in before you can use the new max limit,
test with

```
ulimit -n
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user

Also here is a good article on the caveats in using eventlets
https://code.mixpanel.com/2010/10/29/gevent-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/

Comment: Could you post some content from the links?